Force State/County field to be required in WooCommerce Shipping Calculator
I am trying to make sure that the Shipping State field is selected in the shipping calculator.
Using the solution here works great for the City and Postcode fields like this:
 jQuery('#calc_shipping_city, #calc_shipping_postcode').prop('required', true);

However, I have tried several different ID's and cant get this to work for the State field.


As Shipping state field is displayed optionally depending on the chosen country, you need to target the shipping calculator form changes to set the "required" property, like:
jQuery(function($){
    $('#calc_shipping_city, #calc_shipping_postcode').prop('required', true);

    $(document.body).on('change', 'form.woocommerce-shipping-calculator', function(){
        $('#calc_shipping_state').prop('required', true);
    });
} );

Now it should work.

That worked great. However the popup points to the upper left corner of the state select which covers it and looks like it is pointing to the Country field above.
